# Deploy angular universal app to aws s3 bucket not working ssr

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I was working with angular9 application for making it SEO friendly i need to switch to Angular Universal SSR. I have executed command as below

- ng add @nguniversal/express-engine
- npm run dev:ssr
- npm run build:ssr
- npm run serve:ssr

while execution i face some problems which i solved. The problem is when we run **npm run dev:ssr** whole application is working fine at development mode and in page source code able to see meta tags.

[image]

**Source Code (dev:ssr)**
[image]

But when i run **npm run build:ssr** & **npm run serve:ssr** command i am facing issue with application UI but meta tags are working fine.

I want to deploy my angular universal app to AWS S3 bucket. In **dist** folder **browser** & **Server** folder gets created. What folder i need to upload.. i tried both folders, individual folders and other things but no luck.

Please help me with this i already waste 2 3 days.. give me proper way..

Comment: not sure, but look for your index.html file? that probably needs to end up in the root

Answer (score 2):

You have following options:

EC2 instance with application installed on it
Elastic Beanstalk
ECS + Fargate / EC2 (Dockerised setup) good for long term production setup
Maybe on Lambda (depends on the site)